# Django Tastypie - include to many fields

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I am trying to use the django tastypie but have some troubles. Here is my api.py:

```
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource
from tastypie import fields
from app.models import First, Second, Third

class FirstResource(ModelResource):
    second = fields.ToManyField('app.api.SecondResource', 'second_set', related_name='first', null=True, blank=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = First.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'first'

class SecondResource(ModeResource):
    first = fields.ForeignKey(FirstResource, 'first', full=True)
    third = fields.ToManyField('app.api.ThirdResource', 'third_set', related_name='second', null=True, blank=True, full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Second.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'second'

class ThirdResource(ModelResource):
    poll = fields.ForeignKey(SecondResource, 'second', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Third.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'third'
```

When I try to get the SecondResource with `http://127.0.0.1:8000/app/api/v1/second/` it includes the FirstResource, but I also want the ThirdResource associated.
 For now it only gives me an empty array. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add related name in your Third model:

```
class Third(models.Model):
    second = models.ForeginKey(Second, related_name=thirds)
```

And then in the resource:

```
   class SecondResource(ModeResource):`
       first = fields.ForeignKey(FirstResource, 'first', full=True)
       third = fields.ToManyField('app.api.ThirdResource', 'thirds', null=True, blank=True, full=True)
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the third class name.